# unable to call JNI methods from framework services

Tags: android-ndk

I am trying to develop framework service and manager (xManager and xService ) and jni methods which actually the HAL layer. Here i am facing some issue and unable to call jni methods implemented in .cpp and those are calling from xService -- both are in framework related only but in vendor/xxx/utilities/.

How to link jni methods from .cpp to xservice.java. 
xService.java -- is having jni methods function declaration and the implementation is xx.cpp in jni folder.

Could please help me here.

Comment: Please include the relevant code and error messages.

Comment: Assuming that you have loaded native library successfully, you should share your java declarations for native methods, and related cpp definitions.